# filling the form in declared link

Tags: php, html

I have to declare an html link in my php file, i can do that in the following way

```
echo "<a href='razz.com'>Update</a>";
```

the link razz.com has a form fields(text type) in it, what i want to do is that when i open the link the form fields present in the link needs to be filled by the values that i declare in my initial php page.

the values of the form fields that needs to be filled are obtained from database.

How can i do that? Any tutorials or code snippet are appreciated.

Thank you.

Code snippet of what i am looking for:

a user fills form information which needs to go into database for storage:
the form is as follows:

```
<p>Title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
<p>Report No:<input type="text" name="rno"/></p>
<p>URL:<input type="text" name="url"/></p>
```

now after filling the form, the data will be stored in the database . A page with echo's successful with form information and a link to update the previously entered information will be displayed.

now again this update link contains the form structure , so instead of entering the information which was previously entered. the information already entered needs to be fetched and displayed in the form area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use GET request parameters and the `$_GET` array on the page that is accepting the request to pass values to your link, but only if the http://razz.com/ index page actually accepts your URL parameters.

For instance (see the `stuff` and `otherstuff` GET keys in the URL):

```
echo "<a href='http://razz.com/?stuff=yes&amp;otherstuff=yadayada'>Update</a>";
```

Then the razz.com index(.php):

```
$stuff = $_GET['stuff']; // with the link above, equal to yes
$otherstuff = $_GET['otherstuff']; // with the link above, equal to yadayada

echo "
<h2>$stuff</h2>
<p>I got $otherstuff.</p>
";
```

This would echo on razz.com/index(.php):

```
<h2>stuff</h2>
<p>I got yadayada.</p>
```

You *could* also use the `$_POST` array, but this would require more work and you would need to have a reason to do this (such as the data you're passing is transitory). You could do this by triggering a form, which you could also do a GET request with.

However, your question is not really that well worded. If you can provide more context and direction, that would help.

Comment: hii thanks for your help..as you suggested i added a snippet and more detailed description of the question..thanks.